# Why do I set the time format, but still report an error

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I try to insert data after I set the format, but I get a time format error

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY';

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK', 7782,
TO_DATE('23-JAN-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1300, NULL, 10);
```

ora-01843
I'm wondering how can I handle different time formats, I've come across several different time formats in others code

after `alter session set nls_date_language = 'english'`; now I can insert data normally , there is  a new question no matter how i set
`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='mon-dd-YYYY';` or `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='yyyy.dd.mon';` Nothing changes for my inserted data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldaXp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to handle dates; all you have to do, is to make sure that you're in control over it. Don't rely on implicit datatype conversion and insert strings instead of dates. And - if you insert dates, do it in correct format. Here are several examples:

```
SQL> create table test (datum date);

Table created.
```

Using date literal, which always consists of `date` keyword and date value enclosed into single quotes in format `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
SQL> insert into test values (date '2023-03-27');

1 row created.
```

Using `to_date` function with appropriate format model:

```
SQL> insert into test values (to_date('27.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));

1 row created.
```

`to_date` again, but this time month is *spelled* - in that case, specify which *language* you use:

```
SQL> insert into test values (to_date('mar-27-2023', 'mon-dd-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english'));

1 row created.
```

Alter session so that *string* - entered in that format and language - is correctly recognized:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy.dd.mon';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'croatian';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into test values ('2023.27.ožu');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

According to the last `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, this is table contents:

```
SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
-----------
2023.27.ožu
2023.27.ožu
2023.27.ožu
2023.27.ožu
```

If I alter session and set it differently:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
----------
27.03.2023
27.03.2023
27.03.2023
27.03.2023

SQL>

Or, I can use `to_char` function with any valid format model:

SQL> select to_char(datum, 'yyyy-mon-dd', 'nls_date_language = english') from test;

TO_CHAR(DAT
-----------
2023-mar-27
2023-mar-27
2023-mar-27
2023-mar-27

SQL>
```

---

Yet another example (returning values from `sysdate` function and Scott's `emp` table):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
27.03.2023 09:45:14       --> both date and time are displayed

SQL> select hiredate from emp where rownum = 1;

HIREDATE
-------------------
17.12.1980 00:00:00      --> date is here, but time is set to midnight because that's what column contains

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try   alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';  My time format is normal now , but no matter how I set  NLS_DATE_FORMAT='yyyy.dd.mon'; or 'mon-dd-yyyy'; ...   When I insert data, the displayed results are all the same ，WHY? @Littlefoot

Comment: Have a look at edited answer, please; I added some more info about SELECTING `DATE` datatype values. If you changed date format, then SELECT should reflect it.

Comment: I try something new，but no matter how set ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='xxxxxx';  None of the results changed,please help! SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;  ----2023/3/27 15:42:03  SELECT * FROM emp;
---- 1982/1/23

Comment: See another edit, please. I altered session so that both date and time components are displayed. It works OK (as expected). If you use some GUI tool, did you check its preferences?

Answer (score 1):

Not every language abbreviates the first month of the year
as `"JAN"`.
It appears you want

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='ENGLISH'
```

---

Either that, or consider converting textual month names
to numbers before handing them to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type that consists of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is the format model Oracle uses for **IMPLICIT** string-to-date and date-to-string conversions.

If you are performing an string-to-date or date-to-string conversion and are **EXPLICIT** and specify the format model then your format model will be used in preference to the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

#### Implicit Date Conversions

If you do:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt DATE);
```

Then:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY';

INSERT INTO table_name (dt) VALUES ('27-MAR-2023'); -- A string
INSERT INTO table_name (dt) VALUES (TO_DATE('27-MAR-2023')); -- No format model
```

Then:

- In the first insert, Oracle will convert the string to a date and implicitly calls `TO_DATE` and will implicitly use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model.
- In the second insert, `TO_DATE` is explicitly called but no format model is specified so Oracle will implicitly use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format model.

Both of these `INSERT`s are effectively the same as:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (dt) VALUES (
  TO_DATE(
    '27-MAR-2023',
    (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
  )
);
```

#### Explicit Date Conversions

When you are explicit about the format model:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (dt) VALUES (TO_DATE('27-MAR-2023', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

Then Oracle does not need to use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

#### Handling different date formats

> I'm wondering how can I handle different time formats, I've come across several different time formats in others code

Using implicit conversions is considered bad practice. Always explicitly specify the format model and, if you are using language-specific formats then specify the language in the query:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (dt)
VALUES (TO_DATE('27-MAR-2023', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'));
```

or, better, use a `DATE` literal:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (dt) VALUES (DATE '2023-03-27');
```

Which does not need to be converted from a string to a date and requires no language-specific conversions.

#### Displaying data

> No matter how I set `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='mon-dd-YYYY';` or `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='yyyy.dd.mon';` Nothing changes for my inserted data.

A `DATE` is a binary data type and is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is only used for implicit string-to-date and date-to-string conversions.

If you are **displaying** dates then the database will provide the client application with the binary value of the date and it is then up to the client application to display that binary value in a meaningful way to the user.

If you are using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer (both Oracle products) then they will both use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the default format for displaying dates. If you are using a different client application (which, for your image, it looks like you are, maybe TOAD or PL/SQL Developer) then how it displays dates is something that that client application controls (and not the database) and if you want to change how it formats dates to display them then you will need to change the settings/preferences in that client application.

If you want to use a specific format and be independent of the client application then you can use `TO_CHAR` in a `SELECT` statement to convert the binary `DATE` to a formatted string:

```sql
SELECT dt,                        -- Formatted by the client application
       TO_CHAR(dt),               -- Converted to a string by the database
                                  -- Implicitly uses NLS_DATE_FORMAT as the format
                                  -- model.
       TO_CHAR(dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY') -- Converted to a string by the database
                                  -- Uses the explicitly provided format model.
FROM   table_name;
```

Comment: I really appreciate it, thank you, the PL/SQL Developer I use, it seems to be a problem with the tool, I will look up the relevant information to see how to set it

Comment: sorry to bother you，In setting the PLSQL Developer time format, I have a new question. Since PLSQL has already set the time format, it cannot be easily changed (the format is fixed), so why do we need to change the time format in alter session xxx  code? like EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=''YYYY-MM-DD'''; i always see this code in a procedure. why？

Comment: @Shahana You should not need to do it. Some reasons to do so are if you are: using implicit string-to-date conversions; using `TO_DATE` without specifying a format model; or using `TO_CHAR` without specifying a format model. All of those are considered bad practice and if you are not doing them then setting the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in a procedure is probably pointless. You would be better served by fixing the bad practices and then eliminating setting the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.